# Invalid operation in multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I need two methods to be executing in parallel. `Work()` changes data inside infinite loop. `Represent` puts the changed data in the `TextBox` inside the infinite loop as well.

```
Log log = Log.GetInstance; //singleton
private void Work()
        {
            while (true) { //changing log }
        }   

private async void Represent()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)     
                {   
                    String str = String.Empty;
                    //generating str from log
                    textBox.Text = str;
                } 
            });
        }

private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => Work());
        }
public MainForm()
        {
            Represent();
        }
```

The problem is that `textBox.Text = str;` generates an error `"invalid operation in multiple threads: attempt to access the control "textBox" from a thread in which it was created"`. How to solve that problem? Thanks in advance.
P.S. Suggested method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c) for .NET 4.5 doesn't work because of the infinite loop.

Comment: Hopefully that error message is not literally what it says

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for cross thread changing you need to invoking

use this code :

use this just for elements are in ui like textbox,combobox ,.....
for public elements you don't need this

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => { /*your code*/ }));
```

for your sample :

```
    Log log = Log.GetInstance; //singleton
private void Work()
        {
            while (true) { //changing log }
        }   

private async void Represent()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)     
                {   
                    String str = String.Empty;
                    //generating str from log
                   this.Invoke(new Action(() => { textBox.Text = str;}));
                } 
            });
        }

private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => Work());
        }
public MainForm()
        {
            Represent();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Attempt to access member of System.Windows.Forms.Control from different thread than UI thread will cause cross-thread exception.

Take a look at the this:
[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)